# On ruby on rails I keep getting 'cannot load such file -- sass' error on stylesheet import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm on rails 5.07, ruby 2.6. gem 3.0.3

```html
<title>Simple CMS: <%= @page_title || "Admin area"%></title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag('admin', :media => 'all')%>
```

Admin.css looks like this:

```html
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 * require_tree .
 *= require primary
 *= require admin_additions
 *require mystyle
 *= require_self
 */
```

And the error says:
ExecJS::ProgramError in Subjects#index
Showing C:/Users/Munkhtur/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Following the tutorial on lynda.com.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please copy and paste relevant code sniplets into your question and do not link images.

Comment: Please never use images of code, unless absolutely necessary. And please provide **all** the information upfront about how to reproduce the error -- with a clear explanation of what the error says. *Which* gem versions are you using? What is the *full* error message? What is the folder/file structure? If you're trying to follow a tutorial step-by-step, then perhaps if you could share this guide then we'll be able to reproduce the problem identically?